# Publishing function with example of application

Tags: matlab

I have been trying to publish a function I wrote in matlab. How can I enter variables in order to show the reader that function works with these numbers ? I tried using

```
publish(passage3([1 2 3 4;2 3 4 5]))
```

but I got the following messge:

```
Error in LocateFile elseuf (length(dir(file))==1) Error in publish (line 87) fullPathtoScript=LocateFile(file) Error using passage3 not enough input arguments"
```

When I activate the function on the same example it works great but about publish... How can I solve that?

Comment: Look at the documentation for publish, specifically at the header: Publish Function M-File and Evaluate Code.

Answer (score 0):

Well,I found that the right command for the file func.m is 
    `publish('func.m', struct('codeToEvaluate', 'func(matA,matB,...)', 'showCode', true))`